# Как создать простой переключатель состояния кнопок?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужен простой переключатель состояния кнопок на чистом **JS**.

Например есть **4** кнопки, первые две должны быть видимыми, а последние две должны быть скрытыми. Есть так же две кнопки для переключения **`"вперёд" и "назад"`**.

Нужно, чтобы во время нажатия на кнопку `"вперёд"`, если текущая кнопка, например кнопка "Button Visible One", является видимой, то она так и оставалась видимой, а если является скрытой, например мы дошли до кнопки `Button Hidden One`, то она должна появиться внизу двух видимых кнопок, т.е. внизу `Button Visible` One и `Button Visible Two`.

При переключении на **4** кнопку - **3** должна скаться(т.е. при переключении с `Button Hidden One` на `Button Hidden Two`, `Button Hidden One` должна скаться), а **4** появиться на его месте. При переключении с первой кнопки на последнюю с помощью кнопки `"назад"`, внизу **2** видимых кнопок должна появиться **4** невидимая кнопка, т.е. внизу `Button Visible One` и `Button Visible Two` должна появиться `Button Hidden Two`.

```html
<!-- Cписок с кнопками -->
<ul>
  <li><button class="btn" />Button Visible One</li>
  <li><button class="btn" />Button Visible Two</li>
  <li><button class="btn" />Button Hidden One</li>
  <li><button class="btn" />Button Hidden Two</li>
</ul>

<!-- Кнопки для передвижения -->
<button id="previous">Previos</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Раз 20 перечитал вопрос.... Не понял...

Comment: `Нужно, чтобы во время нажатия на кнопку "вперёд", если текущая кнопка является видимой...` , как это понять?  `Текущая` в моем понимании, это эта  же кнопка, как на нее нажать если вдруг она невидима...??? Методом тыка искать ее по всему экрану?

Comment: `При переключении на 4 кнопку - 3 должна, а 4 появиться на его месте.` - `3 должна` -  ЧТО?  Прыгать, скакать, вызвать полиция...... ???   Вопрос надо переформулировать... Ничего не понятно

Comment: Поправил. Под текущей подразумевается кнопки из списка, а не передвижения.

Comment: к сожалению лучше не стало, все еще не понятно.

Comment: Что конкретно не понятно? Нужно, чтобы во время переключения кнопок скрытые кнопки появлялись.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function step(prev) {
  let child = list.querySelector('[data-hidden="0"]');
  if (child) {
    child.dataset.hidden = 1;
    while (child.dataset.hidden != 0) {
      child = child[prev ? "previousElementSibling" : "nextElementSibling"];
      if (!child) {
        child = list[prev ? "lastElementChild" : "firstElementChild"]
      }
      if (child.dataset.hidden == 1) {
        child.dataset.hidden = 0;
      }
    }
  } else {
    child = list.querySelector('[data-hidden="1"]');
    if (child) {
      child.dataset.hidden = 0
    }
  }
}

previous.addEventListener("click", () => step(true));

next.addEventListener("click", () => step());
```

```css
[data-hidden="1"] {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<!-- Cписок с кнопками -->
<ul id="list">
  <li><button class="btn" />Button Visible One</li>
  <li><button class="btn" />Button Visible Two</li>
  <li data-hidden="1"><button class="btn" />Button Hidden One</li>
  <li data-hidden="1"><button class="btn" />Button Hidden Two</li>
</ul>

<!-- Кнопки для передвижения -->
<button id="previous">Previos</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```